# Can't redirect on button click

Tags: php, html

So I want to redirect to "editcomment.php" when  press the button.

I've tried changing name to onclick, I've also tried to put the button inside  tags to use href.

```
echo("<button class='col-sm-2 border1' name='myButton1()'>");
echo("<p>Bokad</p>");
echo("</button>");

session_start();
$bokning = 0;
$_SESSION['bokningar'] = $bokning;

function myButton1(){
   $bokning = 1;
   header("Location: editcomment.php");
}
```

As mentioned i want it to redirect to editcomment.php and change $bokning to 1, but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't use a PHP function for a redirect. Here are two solutions. Both solutions assume you're not submitting a form with data. If you're doing that, there's a whole different approach.

Note the use of the full URL below.

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/editcomment.php">
   <button class='col-sm-2 border1' name='myButton1()'>
</a>
```

The second is to use javascript. At the bottom of your webpage, do this.

```
<script>
    function myButton1() { 
       window.location.replace("http://yourdomain.com/editcomment.php");
      }

</script>
```

With the above, you'll have to put the onClick() back in your button though.

Comment: Oh I see, is there any way I could asign $bokning with a value with php?

Comment: You could could put it in a hidden input in the html if needed. I don't fully understand the purpose but you could do this: echo  "<input type='hidden' value='" . $bokning . "'>";

Comment: I'm trying to make a variable that changes depending on which button I press(I have more than one), I will then use that to change a certain database value depending on which value $bokning has

Answer (score -2):

You can't call php function directly with html elements.